Stack-to-reach curve to stack-to-reach curve: do you match stack, reach, or the average?
The blue curve at the bottom of the figure is the stack-to-reach for an endurance road bike line I am quite intimate with. I had in the past typically found that Size 54 (ML in the diagram?) fits me well, but after  closer experimentation riding different sizes from this particular line I found that Size L fits me much more. My top-tube clearance is down to a slim 15 mm, but the vastly improved ergonomics tell me with certainty that moving up is right for me. I am much more comfortable on longer rides and much more in control.

The dotted green curve at the top of the figure is the stack-to-reach for one of the gravel bikes I'm contemplating.
(Neither curve is quite that smooth. One of them looks indeed rather vulgar. I smoothed out both here so that we can focus on the substance. You can read why fitting bikes to humans requires using graphs with so many inflection points, but that's not our concern here.)
I'd now like to use my experience with the blue curve to make an educated guess about the size that would most likely fit me on the green curve. Should I conservatively match Stack — given the modest top-tube clearance (and expect Size S to fit), match Reach (selecting Size L and hope that the bike will be a good fit — to a certain limit I don't mind stepping out by leaning if the ride would be more comfortable), or select the intermediate point (Size M)?
Had the two curves been closer or had there been one or more intersections (possibly  the expected outcome when both bikes are of the same type), the problem might be distinct, and perhaps simpler. Can you make initial suggestions for the present case?
To be clear, nothing beats taking 3 bikes out on a ride from a ready stock. This question is about understanding what one can extract from published geometry tables.

For the target gravel bike, do you know if it is a road-like bike or an MTB-inspired bike? The stack on the gravel bike is a lot higher, suggesting an MTB-like bike, which has a short stem. Also, is your road bike curve for performance or endurance bikes?

@WeiwenNg I guess the distance to be traveled is the main distinguishing factor — long for road-like, short for MTB-like. Judging by the stem being anywhere from 90 to 130 mm, I'd say they're aiming for a road-bike-like gravel bike, not an MTB-like one. The road bike is an endurance bike.

I would argue that many things do beat taking a bike for a ride. Only continuous riding for longer periods can show problems with the bike fit. A short ride can feel quite well even on bikes that are quite off.

Stack and reach is of little to no use to compare built bikes. It does not take into consideration the angle of the seat-tube or head-tube, stem length/angle or how tall the stem sits on the frame(spacers). In other words, you can get wildly different sitting positions on bikes with the same stack and reach due to a long list of factors.
IMO, the single best metric for fit is to set the saddle at the correct height, and then measure the distance from the saddle(where the seatpost theoretically would intersect the saddle surface) to the handlebar. This is still not a perfect metric as there is an arc of possible sitting positions with the same number, but this is still my preferred way to compare bikes.
Bikes don't come in continous sizes from factories anyway, so matching reach and see how it feels is a crude ok first step. I'd still prefer my way of doing it in order to get somewhat close to what one is used to if that is the goal.
Try the large, it has similar reach and larger stack so maybe a more upright and comfortable position.

Your metric should yield exactly the same distance if stack and reach of two frames are the same.

@Michael I have explained why that is not the case in the very first paragraph. Stack & reach relates to a bare frame, not a complete bike and does not take into account the seat tube angle either. These factors all change my metric, but not stack & reach.

Seat tube angle doesn’t have an effect on seating position because you can move the saddle fore and aft in the saddle clamp (or even get seatposts with different setback if that’s not sufficient). Same for headtube angle: Just get a stem which is angled more up or down.

@Michael You just prove my point. On two completed different bikes, stack & reach are bad metrics since so many other parts change the position. If you have to swap and replace lots of parts why even bother with stack and reach? Why not just measure what matters, which is what I suggest. S&R is a fine place to ballpark, but useless for fine tuning.

From what I understood from the discussion I had with my bike fitter, you match first saddle height and saddle fore/aft depending on your pedaling style, and then you adjust from that point. For a similar pedaling style and same seat tube angle, you don't need to correct the reach/stack.
Assuming you want the same riding position, you should not compare reach/stack immediately, that are frame measurements, but at the very least add stem height/angle/length, handlebar reach and length of the shifters (if they differ), as what you want to compare is the position on the hoods, not the point where the bars are mounted. Tools like BikeGeoCalc can help for that.
The handlebar width also plays a role, as wider handlebars also require less total reach (but I would assume that between gravel and endurance, you may want the same width - more adventurous gravel bikes will require wider bars though).
Comparing reach and stack has another problem when comparing different disciplines: the different uses require different geometries: gravel bikes will typically be longer for stability on rough terrain, and that is compensated by shorter stems. To take the example of Canyon, the reach difference between the Endurace (Endurance) and the Grail (Gravel race) is 33mm longer for the Grail (for size M), but the stem is also 30mm shorter. The reach different is 1mm. They are not clear on the height of the stem/bar combos on the two bikes, but if they are identical, you would have almost the same riding position on the two bikes, despite the reach difference.

To be clear, nothing beats taking 3 bikes out on a ride from a ready stock. This question is about understanding what one can extract from published geometry tables.

I rather think that nothing beats going to a bike fitter before choosing the bike (you can go with a shortlist of course). They must have a standing bike where you can easily adjust the different parameters, so you can test the different combinations. If you buy the bike from a shop that allows to swap components before buying, you can also offset the cost of the stem/seatpost/saddle/handlebars that you would have needed to buy if the stock one don't fit. Then it depends on the bike fitters, but mine includes size recommendations for life (assuming the same riding style) if I want to rent/buy a new bike, so the price of future components can also be offset. Test rides are useful to test other characteristics such as handling or ride compliance (that is also influenced by the tires though), but not for sizing.

I'm not suggesting this is the the answer, but rather that it is one possible answer. Critiques are welcome.
I’d like to propose here an even simpler method — simpler than the present school of bike fit advising to use Stack & Reach. As the question demonstrates, the practical use of S&R is far from obvious.
Suppose you were not riding a bicycle but were hanging onto a coin-operated shopping-mall toy platform that was trying, rodeo style, to eject you. You’re grabbing handles with your hands, and your (non-spinning) feet are tethered side by side to the platform.
Your comfort during the process, and your success in avoiding ejection, would rely on only one distance: that between your hand-hold and your foot-hold.
We could similarly claim that it is not Stack (S) and Reach (R), per se, that matter during bike fit, but the hypotenuse $\sqrt{S^2 + R^2}$.

This provides a hint for the present problem: to go from Size L to Size M, the one providing the nearest hypotenuse match.

Verbalized critiques welcome. Merely voting down says nothing — particularly not whether your knowledge on the subject matter is scant.
